# How to show the disk usage of each subdirectory in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory, `/var/lib/docker`, which contains several subdirectories:

```
/var/lib/docker$ sudo ls
aufs  containers  image  network  plugins  swarm  tmp  trust  volumes
```

I'd like to find out how big each directory is. However, using the `du` command as follows,

```
/var/lib/docker$ sudo du -csh .
15G .
15G total
```

I don't see the 'breakdown' for each directory. In the examples I've seen in http://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-disk-usage-of-files-and-directories/, however, it seems that I should see it. How might I obtain this overview to see which directory is taking up the most space?

Comment: You can use just du -h and that should give you what your looking for

Comment: Don't use `-s` with `du`, which makes `du` generate summary only.  Try: `du /var/lib/docker | sort -nr`

Comment: @CongMa Without `-s` it will display the whole tree directory, which may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: @vdavid, in that case use `-d` to limit depth.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use asterisk to get info for each directory, like this:

```
sudo du -hs *
```

It will output something like the below:

```
0       backup
0       bin
70M     boot
0       cfg
8.0K    data
0       dev
140K    docs
```

Comment: It is possible to add sorting by (human) size as well, thus: 
`sudo du -sh * | sort -h`

Answer (score 7):

Try using the `max-depth` argument. It  prints the total disk space usage for a directory (or file, with `--all`) only if it is `N`or fewer levels below the command line argument.

For e.g. the following command will show the disk space usage upto 3 level deep subdirectories

`du --max-depth=3 -h`

For informations on N-levels, use this `du --max-depth=N -h` where N is a positive integer.

Answer (score 7):

`ncdu` is also a nice way to analyze disk usage.  It allows to quickly navigate through subdirectories and identify largest directories and files.

It should be available in most distributions official repositories.

Answer (score 4):

Let shell expand the directory contents:

```
du -h *
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `du` for each directory:

```
find . -type d | xargs du -csh
```

Comment: It works because xargs takes stdin and turns it into command-line arguments

Answer (score 2):

In addition,

`du -h <directory>` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition you can simply use :

> du       /directory

This would give of the space used by all of the sub directories inside the parent directory.